# C# 6.0 null-conditional operator in if statements

Tags: c#, linq, null-conditional-operator

Can someone please explain the logic of the null-conditional operator in if statements?

Imagine the following code

```
List<string> items = null;
if (items?.Count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("error");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
```

The above will print OK. Why does it compile when the next block would not?

```
if (items?.Any())    // won't compile but if (items?.Count() == 0) would
{
    ...
}
```

I am guessing the ?. will stop execution when null detected and the entire if is skipped but why is it not the case with "?.Any()"? Just because it's a method whereas "count" is a property?

And why does the Linq extension method Any() require an explicit conversion from Nullable to bool where Count() == 0 compiles with no conversion Nullable to int required?

Comment: There is an overload on `==` to lift the comparison and still return true/false, so the magic is in the `==` operator on `Nullable<T>`. If you try `if (items?.Any() == true)` it will compile.

Comment: Note that, in C# 9, you can write this as `if (items is { Count: > 0 })`. You may or may not find that clearer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if `items` is null, then `items?.Count` is null, too.
and `null == 0` is a comparison that results in false. so the `if` is happy.

but `items?.Any()` will also be null - and `if(null)` is invalid, because null is not a boolean, and cannot be converted to one.

so you simply have to provide a fallback boolean value:

```
if (items?.Any() ?? false) {

}
```

will do the trick

Comment: `if (items?.Any() == true)` is more readable I think

Comment: @HansKilian that's a matter of preference, i (obviously) root for the null coalesce operator. but it would be interesting to see if there's differences in performance.

Comment: Readability is generally more important than performance, I think. At least on the systems I work on. I leave performance to the compiler :) But you're right, of course, that what's more readable is a matter of preference.

Comment: Thanks @FranzGleichmann it makes sense now. The bit I hadn't realised is that you can do "if (null == 0)" which seems odd but it explains why it's happy with "if (items?.Count == 0)".

Comment: There's [no difference in performance](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0AZAlgOwI4G5YFkIAWQuAZmTEQGFEBvWRV5akUxAWQAosAzgBcAPDiEA+RABsAlExZslmAGaJe0gPyoAgtgCeveZs2IVAQ2kCAprMVLWzGA5ckAnLwBEACWsAna09ZCldEAF97B0jlNQ1tPUN5AF4kxCE/AFdbaLYnUKUUDx9/QOCc1gjnNkrKoA=)

Comment: @David It's because both `0` and `null` can be converted to an `int?` (a nullable int).

Comment: @David well if it answers your question, then upvoting&accepting is the traditional reaction ;)

Answer (score 7):

Consider the `null` case.

In `if (items?.Count == 0)`  that becomes `if (null == 0)` and that gives false.

But in `if (items?.Any())` it becomes `if (null)` and that is invalid.

You can use `if (items?.Any() == true)` or `if (items?.Any() ?? false)` or something similar.

I notice that `items.Count == 0` is an error but `items == null` returns Ok in your first example.
That is odd.